# How can resolve "no db_java-6.2 in java.library.path" issue?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, berkeley-db

I started a project using the Oracle BDB XML java API in a Linux(Ubuntu-eclipse) environment.

I proceeded with the installation as follows:

> > cd dbxml-6.1.4
>
> > sh buildall.sh --enable-java
>
> > sh buildall.sh --build-one-berkeleydb
>
> > sh buildall.sh --build-one-dbxml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q19Kj.png)

After that, I imported the jar file into the project as shown in the figure above.

At least there was no problem up to this point.

However, when I run the program after compiling, I get the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Hwz.png)

I searched Google for "no db_java-6.2 in java.lang.library.path" and tried to solve the problem,

but I have not found a clear solution yet.

Any suggestion are appreciated, so please give me some helpful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you build from db-xml sources, did you find `libdb_java-6.2.so` at the output location? If yes, add the path of directory where libdb_java-6.2.so is located to the search path where JRE could find it. In your case (looks like you were using Eclipse), on the `Java Build Path` --> `Libraries` tab, expand the `JRE System Library` node, Edit the `Native Library Location`, add the directory path of `libdb_java-6.2.so` in `Native Library Location`

Comment: Thank you very much